# validation error when uploading file type cert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to upload `.cert` files using a form.

I did set the validation for the input like this :

```
'cert'=>'required|mimes:cert',
```

I'm getting an error when I'm uploading .cert file that the file is not valid.

so I read that the issue is related to the browser `mimes Types`.

any idea how i can make this work?

Comment: how you are sending file from client side? using ajax? or axios? or something else?

Comment: @JunaidAhmad no just submitting the form `action='/route'` no ajax

Comment: are you setting enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag?

Comment: @JunaidAhmad yes

Comment: @LMA_F whats your end goal here. why are you uploading this file can you tell if you dint mind.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using the latest version of laravel. I think you need to replace mime `cert` with `cer` or `ca`. Please see the image below.
[image]

Reference links:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: this does not solve the problem. i need to upload .android cert not ssl cert .the ssl cert extension is .cer which is not what i want :\

Comment: i am not sure if android have any kind of .cert files...
And only apk mime type is supported in laravel for android.